# Add to Home screen dynamic icon for the short cut created in the mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, icons, homescreen

I am using [Matteo Spinelli's Add to Home](https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen) script.

When user clicks on `Add to Home` screen option, shortcut icon is created in the mobile device with the icon given in the link tag.

I want to have dynamic icon for the shortcut created in the mobile device. Is this possible?

In the ATH popup I'm getting the image given with the following link tags:

```
link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16" href="images/addhome/icon-16x16.png"
link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="images/addhome/icon-196x196.png"       
link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/addhome/icon-152x152.png"
```